# PrimeFaces restore colomn visibility

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:datatable>` in which there is some p:column and particularly one `<p:columns>`.

I'm also using one `<p:columnToggler>` to let user to display or hide column.
Memorize his choices is not difficult, it's to restore dynamically his choice which is a problem, especially for `<p:columns>` because there is no get/set for column inside `<p:columns>`. I'm also using a pagination and columntoggler+pagination are not friends.

What is the best way to restore users choices for a `<p:dataTable>` toggler ?

I use PrimeFaces 5.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487243/how-can-i-initially-hide-columns-in-a-pdatatable-with-pcolumntoggler

Comment: After a long search, i found my (partially) own solution. You can find it : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44368&p=138872

Comment: If you think this is **the** answer, please create a real answer, but do NOT forget to include version info (also in your question). And 'links only' are no answers. And reading your post in the PrimeFaces forum, I think you are using an older PF version and not 5.3 am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i forgot to precise : i'm on primefaces 5.1

I found my solution !
In a first time, I put my p:columns inside a p:datatable which is inside a p:column and it's work ! The columntoggler change visibility of this whole column. So i can't hide column per column...
But i also use the pagination and columntoggler/pagination didn't work very well together... I can hide a column but if i change my page (using the paginator) in datatable, the column will re-appear empty ! But if i refresh the whole page, the paginator work correctly...

that's why i used this part of solution : [Primefaces ColumnToggler does'nt work with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817830/primefaces-columntoggler-doesnt-work-with-pagination#)

Precisely a script to check/uncheck column visibility.

```
<script>
      function updateToggles(widget){
         $( widget.jqId + ' .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box').each(function() {
            var chkbox = $(this);
            if(chkbox.hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
               widget.check(chkbox);
            } else {
               widget.uncheck(chkbox);
            }
         });
      }
      </script>
<p:dataTable
         id="datatable-factures"
         value="#{listFactureHandler.table}"
         var="facture"
         label="Facture"
         nativeElements="true"
         paginator="true"
         rowKey="#{facture.id}"
         rowSelectMode="checkbox"
         selection="#{listFactureHandler.selection}"
         sortBy="#{facture.dateFacture.time}"
         sortOrder="descending">
         <f:facet name="header">
            <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Personnaliser" style="float:right;" />
            <p:columnToggler widgetVar="columnToggler" id="columnToggler" datasource="datatable-factures" trigger="toggler" ><p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{dsHandler.onToggleColumn}"/></p:columnToggler>
            <p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="updateToggles(PF('columnToggler'))"/>
         </f:facet>
         <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update=":formulaire:insert-actions" />
         <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update=":formulaire:insert-actions" />
         <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update=":formulaire:insert-actions" />
         <p:column selectionMode="multiple" styleClass="text-center" toggleable="false" />
                         [...]
         <p:column id="columns-champs-perso" headerText="Champs Personnalisés" visible="false">
  <p:dataTable id="subfacture" value="#{facture}">
     <p:columns headerText="#{champs.libelle}" id="champspersos#{index}" value="#{listFactureHandler.dossier.champsPersonnalises}" columnIndexVar="index" var="champs">
        <h:outputText value="#{facture.getChampPersonnalise(champs.code).valeur}" />
     </p:columns>
  </p:dataTable>
```

An handler (dsHandler) memorize datatable states.
On pre-rendering, i do something like that :

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = objlState.getColumnsVisibles();
for (String id : map.keySet()) {
   Column objCol = (Column) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(id);
   if (objCol != null) {
      objCol.setVisible(map.getOrDefault(id, true));
   }
}
```

I memorize columns id, not indexes because columntoggler return columnIndex+visibility and did not pay attention to columns which are not rendered. (but datatable.getChildCount() return column number and take care of not rendered columns.

In hope that will help someone a day ;)