# p:dataTable nativeelements property

Tags: primefaces

Yesterday a colleague was dealing with an issue with a `p:dataTable` compoment he finally solved it by adding the property `nativeelements="true"` into it.

Neither of us could find what this property does, he just copied it from another datatable from the same application, so I was wondering what does the "nativeelements" property do, where does it come from and which components have also this property?

As said before, I couldn't find anything in the documentation. I also googled a lot and searched in SO and the only answer I could find containing the keyword "nativeelements" whas [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171998/primefaces-restore-colomn-visibility)

I'd be very thankful if someone could explain this.

Comment: Sorry, you cannot be serious. The 6.1 docs contains an description of the attributre. If no other components have this in the docs, it is just not there. And google gave me almost a dozen of hits... And if you remove it and look at the differences in the browser you'll get a hint too...

Comment: Is this a joke? I swear i've been a while searching and couldn't find it. Please close the question before my rep goes to hell

Comment: Lol! Casted a sympathy upvote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PrimeFaces User Guide (6.1)](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf):

> nativeElements: Uses native radio-checkbox elements for row selection.